# How to create a Dictionary using foreach statement

Tags: c#, dictionary, foreach

I have a model for some tasks, in each task I had to write down the name of the client,
now I have another model for clients that contains their id, name, adress and phone number.
I can create a customer manually but when i create a task, i am supposed to have a dropdownlist that contains every customer that I created

It's pretty hard for me to explain to you... I know I have to create a dictionnary and add the customers in that dictionnary with a foreach. can any1 help me by showing me some examples?
if you need more details let me know

appreciate the help

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
namespace TaskManager.Models
{
    public class Client
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Nom { get; set; }
        public string Adresse { get; set; }
        public int NumeroTelephone { get; set; }

        public static List<Client> GetList()
        {
            string cStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ListTask"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(cStr))
            {
                string requete = "SELECT * FROM TableClient";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(requete, cnx);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                try
                {
                    cnx.Open();
                    SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    List<Client> clientList = new List<Client>();
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        Client t = new Client();
                        t.Nom = (string)dataReader["Nom"];
                        t.Adresse = (string)dataReader["Adresse"];
                        t.NumeroTelephone = (int)dataReader["NumeroTelephone"];
                        clientList.Add(t);
                    }
                    dataReader.Close();
                    return clientList;
                }
                finally
                {
                    cnx.Close();
                }
            }

        }
        public static Client FindOne(int id)
        {
            string cStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycnx"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(cStr))
            {
                string requete = "SELECT * FROM TableClient WHERE id = " + id;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(requete, cnx);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                try
                {
                    cnx.Open();
                    SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    Client t = new Client();
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        t.id = (int)dataReader["id"];
                        t.Nom = (string)dataReader["Nom"];
                        t.Adresse = (string)dataReader["Adresse"];
                        t.NumeroTelephone = (int)dataReader["NumeroTelephone"];
                    }
                    dataReader.Close();
                    return t;
                }
                finally
                {
                    cnx.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        public bool SaveAsNew()
        {
            string cN = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycnx"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(cN))
            {
                // Utilisation de la connexion
                string requete = "INSERT INTO TableClient (Nom, Adresse, NumeroTelephone)";
                requete += "VALUES (@Nom, @Adresse, @NumeroTelephone)";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(requete, cnx);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                //définir les paramètres
                cmd.Parameters.Add("Nom", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("Adresse", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("NumeroTelephone", SqlDbType.Int);
                //donner des valeurs aux paramètres
                cmd.Parameters["Nom"].SqlValue = this.Nom;
                cmd.Parameters["Adresse"].SqlValue = this.Adresse;
                cmd.Parameters["NumeroTelephone"].SqlValue = this.NumeroTelephone;
                cnx.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cnx.Close();
                return true;
            }
        }
        public bool Update()
        {
            string cN = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycnx"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(cN))
            {
                // Utilisation de la connexion
                string requete = "UPDATE Task SET ";
                requete += "Nom=@Nom,";
                requete += "Adresse=@Adresse,";
                requete += "Numero de telephone=@NumeroTelephone,";
                requete += "WHERE Id = " + this.id;

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(requete, cnx);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                //définir les paramètres
                cmd.Parameters.Add("Nom", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("Adresse", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("NumeroTelephone", SqlDbType.Int);
                //donner des valeurs aux paramètres
                cmd.Parameters["Nom"].SqlValue = this.Nom;
                cmd.Parameters["Adresse"].SqlValue = this.Adresse;
                cmd.Parameters["NumeroTelephone"].SqlValue = this.NumeroTelephone;
                cnx.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cnx.Close();
                return true;
            }

        }
        public static bool Destroy(int id)
        {
            string cN = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycnx"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(cN))
            {
                string requete = "DELETE FROM TableClient WHERE Id = " + id;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(requete, cnx);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cnx.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cnx.Close();
                return true;
            }
        }
```

this is not working

```
        public static readonly Dictionary<int, string> Clients = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {                
                       foreach C in Client.GetList()
            {Clients.Add(id, "test" }   
                    }




    }
```

Here is an example of the same thing that is working, but I have to manually add each item into the dictionnary...basically the first dictionnary is supposed to go on my model for client which I created and get every client in the and add them to the dictionnary...hope I am not making this too difficult for you.

```
public static readonly Dictionary<int, string> Priorities = new Dictionary<int, string>
        {
            { 0, "Choisir une valeur!" },
            { 1, "1 - Pas urgent pantoute!" },
            { 2, "2 - Bah! ça serait le fun que ça soit fait un jour!" },
            { 3, "3 - Pour hier!" }
        };
```

Comment: Please narrow down the scope of your question, show your code and highlight the particular problem you are experiencing. Best regards,

Comment: there are some words in french but basically it's the very last part

Comment: I know the code is wrong on the last one...I don't know what to do

Comment: What exactly is wrong with this code - could you please clarify?

Comment: It's not working because of the multiple syntax errors. Read more on Method statement block and foreach syntax in C# (link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to declare your `Clients` dictionary as `readonly`, unless you're going to create it in the static constructor. If that's what you want to do, then you have to create a static constructor:

```
// static dictionary of clients
public static readonly Dictionary<int, string> Clients;

// This is the static constructor for the Client class
static Client()
{
    // create and populate the Clients dictionary
    Clients = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    foreach (var c in GetList())
    {
        Clients.Add(c.id, c.Nom);
    }
}
```

If you do that, though, then you'll have to add new items to the dictionary whenever you create a new record, and update the dictionary if you change a name. Remember, the static constructor is run *one time*--when the `Client` type is first accessed.

You can shorten that code in the `Client` constructor so that it's a single LINQ statement:

```
Clients = GetList().ToDictionary(c => c.id, c => c.Nom);
```

It looks like what you really want, though, is something that will build the dictionary on demand. In that case, you would have a `GetClientsDictionary` method that you can call when you need it:

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> GetClientsDictionary()
{
    return GetList().ToDictionary(c => c.id, c => c.Nom);
}
```